# The call is ambiguous MVC ViewBag hidden input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewbag

my application is asp.net I am passing a variable from the controller to a view using:

```
 public ActionResult Create(long? learnerID)
    {
        learnerID = 211;
        ViewBag.learnerID = learnerID.Value;
        return View();
    }
```

In the view:

```
 <input type="text" value="<%=  ViewBag.learnerID %>" id="Learner_ID" name="Learner_ID" />
```

The value 211 shows in form and I can save it, however if I change the input type to hidden or use style="display:none"  I get the following error:

```
The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(string, params object[])' and 'System.IO.TextWriter.Write(char[])'
```

Would appreciate your suggestions.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a call to ToString()

```
<input type="text" value="<%=  ViewBag.learnerID.ToString() %>" id="Learner_ID" name="Learner_ID" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use <%=HtmL.Hidden("Learner_ID", ViewBag.learnerID)%>.
But better use strongly typed view and typed Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.LearnerID)

Comment: Thanks Kirill, I got this error: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<Evaluation.Models.CTAFormEdit>' has no applicable method named 'Hidden' but appears to have an extension method by that name. Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched. Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax.  I do have       public long Learner_ID { get; set; } in the model.